# Flexbox: how to change order and direction simultaneously?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I have 3 divs which correctly display one next to the other, horizontally, like so:

```
div0  div1  div2
```

When media width is less than 600px, I would very much like the divs to be displayed like so:

```
div0  div2
   div1
```

Right now I could only manage to get this:

```
div0
div2
div1
```

I changed the direction and order like so:

```
.wrapper  {
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .div1 {
        -webkit-order: 3;
        order: 3;
      }
}
```

I understand why it cannot give desired result, but I have no idea where to go from there. I suppose it has to do with `flex-wrap`, but I am not sure.

---

Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/nQcCId?p=preview) for this issue.

---

I suppose this must be trivial for some, but I am very new to FlexBox.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is *not* to change the `flex-flow` property, because by switching to column, you will prevent the elements from being arranged side by side in the way you wanted to. If you have a closer look at your desired layout, it is still going to be *row*-based, so `flex-flow: row` should remain (it is default when undeclared, so we simply do not redeclare it as `column`).

The solution would be to allow wrapping by using `flex-wrap: wrap` instead. Flex elements by default have wrapping turned off, but you can enable that. To ensure that `.div0` and `.div2` will remain on the first row, assigned them a `flex-basis` value that sums up to 100%. I have used 50% for each, since you didn't specify how their relative widths should be.

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
      .wrapper  {
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
      .div0, .div2 {
        flex-basis: 50%;
      }
      .div1 {
        -webkit-order: 3;
        order: 3;
        flex-basis: 100%;
      }
}
```

See working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/1gv0oPASUcGbK70Gn55k?p=preview

Comment: great explanation, thanks! Small typo in your answer, should be: "To ensure that .div0 and .div2 will remain on the first row". You saved me hours of head scratching!

Comment: @Manube Fixed that, glad that it helped :)